# Is there any simple way to change UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal scroll animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want the UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal to scroll from the left instead of the right (the opposite way of the default) in a page view controller. 
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I've been in this situation before and couldn't figure it out using the UIPageViewController. I'm not sure what your intent on your project is but this might help.

Use a UIScrollView and place the amount of UIView's you need inside. At the point you could just create a CGPoint and set your UIScrollView's content offset to your CGPoint. This way you would start at the last page(view) and can scroll to the left instead of the right. Something like this below. You can perform this in your viewDidLoad method.

```
CGPoint nameYourPoint = CGPointMake(640.0,568,0);
self.yourScrollViewName.contentOffset = nameYourPoint;
```

Comment: I just used the pageViewController template (selection from apple) All i'm doing is adding images

Comment: Yeah I understand and that's how I started as well but didn't want to waste too much time so I went with a horizontal scrollView instead. Hope you find your solution. I would be curious on how it's done with the pageViewController template.

Comment: I figured out the solution. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out fairly simply: 
When adding objects into the array of images, I added them in backwards like so:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 81; i++) {
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%i.gif", i];
    [self.mArray insertObject:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] atIndex:0];
```

After that, in the root view controllers viewDidLoad method, I simply started the images at the end of the array

```
ModelController *objModelController = [ModelController new];
DataViewController *startingViewController = [self.modelController viewControllerAtIndex:[objModelController.mArray count]-1 storyboard:self.storyboard];
```

note:for some reason the length wasnt working, so I had to just add 2 empty objects to the beginning of the array and use

```
[objModelController.mArray count]-1
```

Hope this helps everyone out!